# Changing the value dynamically in input tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm creating a Todo app. Although I'm able to create todos and display them, each todo I've created with an input tag which should change the name of todo.

My code:

```js
    const Hello = props => {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {props.todos.map((todo, id) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <p key={todo.id}>{todo}</p>
                  <input type="text" onChange={() => props.changed(event, id)} />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    
    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        todoItem: [],
        todoText: "",
        id: 0
      };
      addTodoHanlder = event => {
        let todoValue = this.state.todoText;
        let incID = this.state.id + 1;
        this.setState({
          todoItem: [...this.state.todoItem, todoValue],
          id: incID
        });
        this.clearTodoText();
        todoValue = "";
      };
    
      clearTodoText() {
        this.setState({ todoText: "" });
      }
    
      handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ todoText: event.target.value });
      };
    
      todoNameChangeHandler = (event, id) => {
        let todoVal = event.target.value;
        const todoIndex = this.state.todoItem.findIndex(el => {
          return el.id == id;
        });
        let todoUpdate = {...this.state.todoItem[todoIndex]}
        todoUpdate = todoVal;
        this.setState({
          todoItem: todoUpdate
        });
      };
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Todo"
              value={this.state.todoText}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <button onClick={this.addTodoHanlder}>AddTodo</button>
            <Hello
              todos={this.state.todoItem}
              changed={this.todoNameChangeHandler}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I just want to assign the todoItem found with id to:

```
let todoUpdate = {...this.state.todoItem[todoIndex]}
```

and then update it via `setState`.
But having hard time doing that and I'm getting below error.

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
hello
/src/Hello.js:7:21
   4 | return (
   5 |   <div>
   6 |     <ul>
>  7 |       {props.todos.map((todo, id) => {
     |  

             ^
```

Also, I don't want to use the `reduce` method.

Comment: Working example as in?Do you mean to part where my code was working?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is below:

```
  todoNameChangeHandler = (event, id) => {
```

right here you assign the value of the `event.target` to `todoVal`:

```
    let todoVal = event.target.value;
    const todoIndex = this.state.todoItem.findIndex(el => {
      return el.id == id;
    });

    let todoUpdate = {...this.state.todoItem[todoIndex]} // <- dead code
    todoUpdate = todoVal; // <- dead code if you just used todoVal
```

then set the state with it here, overwriting `this.state.todoItem` with a string:

```
    this.setState({
      todoItem: todoUpdate
    });
  };
```

If I try this...

```
  todoNameChangeHandler = (event, id) => {
    let todoVal = event.target.value;
    const todoIndex = this.state.todoItem.findIndex(el => {
      return el.id == id;
    });
    let todoUpdate = {...this.state.todoItem[todoIndex]}
    todoUpdate.push(todoVal);
    this.setState({
      todoItem: todoUpdate
    });
  };
```

that opens up a whole new chain of problems...

You're calling `.map` on a string.  That's why you're getting the error you're getting.  But sometimes you want it to be an object `{}`, but `Object` has no method `.map` so you'll need to use an array `[]`.  Get your data types straightened out first.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I was very helpful, I understood where exactly i was going wrong.